# Some applications can't show up in Panel on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, panel, menu-bar

Nautilus, gedit, gvim, LibreOffice, Audacious and gimp have no application menu so that I can't find File,Edit, etc.. But Google Brower, Firefox and Okular is ok.

No menu bar display:

[image]

Has menu bar is displayed:

[image]

When I execute the command `sudo service lightdm restart`,these applications display normally. I write the command into `/etc/rc.local` and `~/.profile`, but it is useless.

**The problem occur after I install gvim.**
I execute these command to install gvim:

```
tar xvf vim-7.4.tar.bz2
cd  ./vim74/src
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev  
sudo apt-get install libgnome2-dev libgnomeui-dev libgtk2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev libbonoboui2-dev libcairo2-dev libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxt-dev 
./configure --enable-gui=gtk2 --prefix=/home/pmsl/DeveloperTools/Vim
make
sudo make install
```

I try to reinstall ubuntu-desktop, unity, lightdm and remove libncurses5-dev, libgnome2-dev, libgnomeui-dev, libgtk2.0-dev, libatk1.0-dev, libbonoboui2-dev, libcairo2-dev, libx11-dev, libxpm-dev and libxt-dev.

I can't find problem by the `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`.

**boot computer lightdm.log:**

```
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.18.1, UID=0 PID=1106
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf
[+0.26s] DEBUG:   [SeatDefaults] is now called [Seat:*], please update this configuration
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.27s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating user session
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.27s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.97s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x

[+0.98s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Plymouth is running on VT 1, but this is less than the configured minimum of 7 so not replacing it
[+0.98s] DEBUG: Quitting Plymouth

[+1.02s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+1.02s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+1.02s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+1.02s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+1.02s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Launching X Server
[+1.02s] DEBUG: Launching process 1215: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+1.02s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+1.02s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+1.02s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+2.65s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 1215
[+2.65s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Got signal from X server :0
[+2.65s] 
[Thread 0x7fffc3eef700 (LWP 5295) exited]DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+2.66s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+2.66s] DEBUG: Session pid=1442: Started with service 'lightdm-autologin', username 'pmsl'
[+2.70s] DEBUG: Session pid=1442: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+2.70s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+2.70s] 
[Thread 0x7fffc3eef700 (LWP 5295) exited]DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
[+2.70s] DEBUG: Session pid=1442: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
[+2.70s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/pmsl
[+2.70s] DEBUG: Session pid=1442: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+2.84s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+2.84s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c1
[+2.84s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c1
[+2.84s] DEBUG: Session c1 is already active
```

**restart service lightdm.log:**

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.18.1, UID=0 PID=3548
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG:   [SeatDefaults] is now called [Seat:*], please update this configuration
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.01s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating user session
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.02s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.02s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.02s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Launching X Server
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Launching process 3554: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.02s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 3554
[+0.26s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Got signal from X server :0
[+0.26s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Session pid=3565: Started with service 'lightdm-autologin', username 'pmsl'
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Session pid=3565: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Session pid=3565: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/pmsl
[+0.27s] 
[Thread 0x7fffc3eef700 (LWP 5295) exited]DEBUG: Session pid=3565: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+0.29s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+0.29s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c2
[+0.29s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c2
[+0.29s] DEBUG: Session c2 is already active
```

**I don't like execute the command "sudo service lightdm restart" manually when I boot my computer.**

```
[Thread 0x7fffc3eef700 (LWP 5295) exited]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, you could try to move the menu bar to the application windows:
http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus

See instructions under "(ii) Show Menu In Window's Title Bar".

Log off, log on -- worked for me!

Cheers,
Thilo

Comment: Log off, log on -- it is meant that ubuntu restart lightdm service.it worked for me.
But if I reboot computer,it still have the same problem.

Comment: OK, I moved the menus to the applications, rebooted the computer and everything is fine. I see the menus in the titlebar of each application if I hold the mouse pointer over the titlebar.

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen to have the menu bar in the application window, and have the menu bar always visible. With my set-up, I have the same problem, except for one difference: I have two different variants of it. Either an application (such as LibreOffice) is completely missing the menu bar, or an application (such as gnome-terminal) has its menu bar doubled. Both problems appear right after reboot, and disappear if I log out and back in. That is, completely without adjusting any settings or running any commands; plain logout-login cures the problem. Well, for the most apps -- some apps still present their menu bar doubled occasionally.

I hope someone could tell me which part of the system I could point my bug report to, as for now,  I have no idea of which component might be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in other forum (cannot take credit), open a command window and enter the following command:

restart unity-panel-service

This worked for me - at least until a more permanent fix is made.